# Does MySQL's Connector/J work with MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mariadb, mysql-connector, connector-j

I'm attempting to connect to my MariaDB database using Connector/J from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), but this fails to work and MariaDB logs `

> "[Warning] Aborted connection 12 to db: 'enwikt_parsed' user:
>   'javawiki' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication
>   packets)".

`

It occurs to me that I just assumed Connector/J from MySQL would just work with MariaDB, but now I'm not so sure. I know MariaDB has their own Java API/Connector, but I'm using someone else's code to [parse](https://github.com/componavt/wikokit) wiktionary, and therefore can't use it.

Before I try some more involved solutions, I'd like to know if I'm trying to fix something that wasn't meant to be used this way in the first place.

Comment: Can you please share your database and connector's version respectively?

Comment: I'm using Connector/J 8.0.17 and MariaDB 10.4.6-1 - I assumed compatibility 'in practice' would be good enough.

Comment: As connectors are back compaitable, ideally it should have worked. But you can try downgrading your connector. In the specification for mysql mariadb compaitablity, these versions are not listed, so hard to say.

Comment: What version should I downgrade to? Would it be better to downgrade MariaDB instead perhaps?

Comment: You can try downgrading MariaDB to 10.2 (just speculation). Do share results here as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, MySQL's Connector/J is compatible with MariaDB. You need to check version though.

> For all practical purposes, MariaDB is a binary drop in replacement of
>   the same MySQL version (for example MySQL 5.1 -> MariaDB 5.1, MariaDB
>   5.2 & MariaDB 5.3 are compatible. MySQL 5.5 is compatible with MariaDB 5.5 and also in practice with MariaDB 10.0, MySQL 5.6 is compatible with MariaDB 10.0 and MySQL 5.7 is compatible with MariaDB 10.2)

Refer : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

> All MySQL connectors (PHP, Perl, Python, Java, .NET, MyODBC, Ruby,
>   MySQL C connector etc) works unchanged with MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

My observation using MySql Connector jdbc driver(8.0.17) with Mariadb(10.6.10) on Linux. The microsecond precision in case of datetime(6) columns is not stored correctly. It just ignores the millisecond, microsecond precision. However replacing the MySQL connector jdbc driver with MariaDB connector j(3.1.0) correctly stores the milliseconds and microseconds precision.