# Can't install mysql library in Pycharm

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am trying to install mysql using PyCharm.

I get this error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
Collecting mysql
  Using cached mysql-0.0.2.tar.gz (1.9 kB)
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz (88 kB)

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Users/ricochetnkweso/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-install-9uhsqjjy/mysqlclient_826a924a2869420fbfa9349807b2e145/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-install-9uhsqjjy/mysqlclient_826a924a2869420fbfa9349807b2e145/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-w9uge2w2
     cwd: /private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-install-9uhsqjjy/mysqlclient_826a924a2869420fbfa9349807b2e145/
Complete output (15 lines):
mysql_config --version
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
mariadb_config --version
/bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
mysql_config --libs
/bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-install-9uhsqjjy/mysqlclient_826a924a2869420fbfa9349807b2e145/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-install-9uhsqjjy/mysqlclient_826a924a2869420fbfa9349807b2e145/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs")
  File "/private/var/folders/x_/_3xykb3s1hl53blcpm28whhc0000gn/T/pip-install-9uhsqjjy/mysqlclient_826a924a2869420fbfa9349807b2e145/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
    raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
OSError: mysql_config not found
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.1; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/ricochetnkweso/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Should I install MySQL using the terminal? I'm not sure what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758141/getting-error-command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-when-trying-to-install) looks very similar but at the end they get "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0" is needed.  The end of your output says "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output."

Can you click on where it says "check the logs" and see if it tells you anything?  Or take a wild guess and install VC++ and see if that's the problem.

It sure wouldn't hurt to create a virtual environment and run pip intall mysqlclient to see if it give more info.