# How can I check compatibility between Mysql and MariaDB connectors

Tags: java, mysql, maven, mariadb

I have a java maven project that use the mysql connector to connect my database. This connector is specified in my `pom.xml` file this way :

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.25</version>
</dependency>
```

I have to migrate this project from MySQL to MariaDB, so I've updated my `pom.xml` file this way :

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
   <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
   <version>????</version>
</dependency>
```

But for this, I'd like to alter the connector so that I use the most recent MariaDB connector that is still compatible with the version of the MySQL connector that I'm using (so the 5.1.25). But I have no idea of how I can find this information. Is there some correspondence table that I'm missing, or should I just try each versions of the MariaDB connector until my project refuse to compile ?

Comment: See if you will find something useful here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

Comment: From what I do understand here they speak of compatibility between the versions of the databases where all I need is to change the connector of my code, so I don't think this applies to the problem

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57156119/does-mysqls-connector-j-work-with-mariadb#:~:text=Yes%2C%20MySQL's%20Connector%2FJ%20is%20compatible%20with%20MariaDB.